# Zabbix monitor devices in private network from outside

Tags: zabbix, private-network

I have zabbix-server with Public IP on AWS (EC2 Amazon Linux 2).
I would like to use this server to monitor devices (VMs, printers etc.) inside our company private network. I have full access to the network/devices and AWS EC2 instance.
Should I install zabbix-proxy in company network and then set up connection between zabbix-server and endpoint which has static public ip with port-forwarding? Or just port forwarding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zabbix proxy is the recommended method. Several benefits over directly monitoring the endpoints:

- Reduces the needed connectivity between the sites to a single TCP port.
- Reduces the amount of network traffic.
- All traffic can be easily encrypted between both sites.

Proxy can operate in either active or passive mode:

- Active - proxy connects to the Zabbix server (likely preferred in this case).
- Passive - Zabbix server connects to the proxy.

Comment: Of course you're right about advantages of zabbix proxy. But what I mean... 
Am I thinking correctly? 
Install zabbix proxy, which will collect for me all metrics for hosts/devices inside the company internal network and using port forwarding set up connection to zabbix server which is outside of our network in AWS?

Comment: In general, yes - whether it's port forwarding or plain TCP connection, it does not matter. Note that proxy can operate in passive or active mode - that is, connections can come from AWS, or go to it.

Comment: Stupid question... Active mode and internet connection, so proxy can send data over internet to the server specified in the config file. 
All in the docs even in the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8pb8NjCEgBg

Thank you for help!